# Prove that for every $k \geq 1$, there exist a connected graph $G$ of genus $k$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that for every $k \geq 1$, there exist a connected graph $G$ of genus $k$

Here is what I think the proof should be.

Let's represent $S_k$ as a regular $4k$- gon as following

[image]

Define $H$ to be a pseudograph such that at each vertex of the $4k-gon$ there is a vertex of $H$, so there is only one vertex in $H$ because the vertex of $4k-gon$ are identical in this processing. Let each side of $4k-gon$ be the edge of $H$ then $H$ has $2k$ edge, each of which is a loop like this

[image]

Now we can see that there is only one region, clearly this region is 2-cell, so there exist a 2-cell embedding of $H$ in $S_k$.

Now from $H$ we can subdivide each lop twice to produce a graph $G$. So the order of $G$ will be $4k$ plus the center vertex of $H$ and the size of $G$ will be $4k$ plus $2k$ edges in $H$. And ofcourse $G$ also have only one region, which implies that $G$ is also 2-cell embedding in $S_k$. This mean we have found a graph of order $4k+1$ and size $6k$ such that embedding genus $k$ for all $k \geq 1$

I think this proof is ok, but I'm not so sure if I missed anything. I also wonder if there is simpler proof than this one.